# JPA EmbeddedId is null after persisting

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Let's say I have 2 JPA entites

```
@Entity
public class MyComplexEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private MyComplexEntityId id;
    private String text;

    public MyComplexEntity() {
    }

    public MyComplexEntity(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public MyComplexEntityId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(MyComplexEntityId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyComplexEntity{" + "id=" + id + ", text=" + text + '}';
    }

}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class MyComplexEntityId {

    @Column
    private long id;

    public MyComplexEntityId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MyComplexEntityId() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyComplexEntityId{" + "id=" + id + '}';
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to persist a new MyComplexEntity object like this

```
MyComplexEntity entity = new MyComplexEntity("something");
em.persist(entity);
System.out.println(entity);
```

and what I get is this:

```
MyComplexEntity{id=null, text=something}
```

Why is the id null there? If I do the same thing with a primitive primary key type, the id is correctly set after persisting. I've also tried the following things:

1. Calling `em.flush();` after the persist: does nothing
2. Calling `em.refresh(entity);` after the persist: Exception telling me that the entity is no longer in the database (which is wrong)
3. Trying `em.merge()` instead of `em.persist()`: Same result, as expected
4. Calling `em.contains(entity);` returns true, so the entity is actually attached
5. Putting the `em.persist();` in a separate transaction by executing it in a separate method using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

There has to be some kind of problem with persist(); when using an @EmbeddedId, but I just don't get it.

Comment: You cannot put GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) on a complex mapping.  It needs to go within the embeddedId class, and you need to instantiate a MyComplexEntityId  instance for your new Entity.   You will also need to flush to the database to ensure that values are assigned as identity values are assigned by the insert.

Comment: You, sir, are my new personal hero. That was exactly correct, it works now!

Comment: Shouldn't I somehow mark this question as answered and give credits to the one who answered it? This is my first non-reading experience with SO, sorry ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) on a complex mapping. It needs to go within the embeddedId class, and you need to instantiate a MyComplexEntityId instance for your new Entity. You will also need to flush to the database to ensure that values are assigned as identity values are assigned by the insert.